# How to fetch list view Id from URL onClick of List View Button

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, list-view

I am using list view button to call lightning component. I wanted to fetch the list view Id from URL on click of list view button and pass it to lightning component. At the moment I am hardcoding the list view Id. I am not sure how to make it dynamic. Need help on this...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above issue.

```
var vfRetURLInSFX = '{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.vfRetURLInSFX)}';
```

Using above code snippet we can fetch the page URL from Lightning List View Button...